# C++ and virtual destructors

Tags: c++, memory-management, virtual, new-operator

I am writing a utility class in an application in which they may or may not be future derivations. I dont have any virtual functions (the general guideline for using virtual dtors), and so given my memory restrictions I choose not to have a virtual destructor in this utility class.

A few programmers later - someone adds to my utility class by deriving from it. Now if, anywhere in the code my new class in new'd and deleted the correct dtor will not be called as the base class dtor was not made virtual (see example code).

Other than going back and changing the base class - what solutions are there in this case?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class utility {
  int i, j;

  public:
    utility () { cout << "utility ctor\n";};
   ~utility () { cout << "utility dtor\n";};
    void dosomething () { cout << "haha\n";};
};

class addtoutility: public utility  {
  char *ch;

  public:
   addtoutility () { ch= new char(); cout << "added ctor\n";};
  ~addtoutility () { delete ch; cout << "added dtor\n";};
   void andnowaddsomefunctionality () {};
};

int main () {
  utility *u  = new addtoutility();
  //lots of interesthing code
  delete u;
}
```

Comment: If someone is going to derive from a non-virtual base, then we would hope they would be careful to never use base-class pointers for their objects.

Comment: I wonder why anyone would want to derive from utility in the first place... is there any use for that? Does anyone know a better example, closer to real code?

Comment: Inheritance is not to reuse code, but rather to be used by existing code (i.e. you should not derive to reuse the base class, but so that code that works with your base will work with the new type). From that standpoint, if the class does not have any virtual function, it should not be derived, and that is where the problem lays.

Answer (score 6):

Your base class is not polymorphic so there is little value to having a pointer-to-base in any case. Your base class documents the fact that it is not polymorphic by not using the `virtual` keyword anywhere.

If someone wants to use it as the base class to a polymorhpic hierarchy then they can add a `virtual` destructor to the first class they derive from it and, where necessary, hold pointers to that base class type.

You can't prevent programmers who come later from digging their own traps but there is nothing wrong with a non-polymorhphic class and you don't need to do anything to it to "make it safe".

As evidence that this is common and acceptable practice, you need only take a look at the standard library. There are many classes (strictly, the majority of them are class templates) with no virtual functions and no virtual destructor.

Comment: Indeed, it's whoever writes the derived class that should check if they can safely use their base classes, not the other way around.

Comment: Ok, thx!- I wanted to make sure that's the case (as in the writer of the base class is not responsible n its common practice, STL is a good example!). Scott Meyers presents a similar situation in Effective C++ (2nd ed) item 14, but does not present a solution or come out and say its not the base class writers responsibility - I guess its implied ;)

Answer (score 3):

- Delete it through a pointer of the correct type. Since none of the other methods are virtual there really is no point to treating it polymorphically.

Works:

```
addtoutility *u  = new addtoutility();

delete u;
```

- Make it virtual. If you're worried about the overhead then it's likely negligible.
- Use static inheritance using CRTP. The only problem is that this may take up more memory than a vtable.

Comment: One way to ensure you delete it through the correct pointer type is to manage it using `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` (and, of course, only allocate it dynamically when you really need to).

Comment: *overhead might be negligible, specially if the compiler sees that nothing inherits from it* --whether it is negligible or not is one issue, but the compiler cannot make any assumption based on the fact that there are no derived types. The whole purpose of virtual functions is that someone can create a derived class with a final overrider *later* and it will work. The compiler must allow *now* for this to happen in the *future*

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Not even multi-pass compilers that perform whole program optimization? (I realize that compilers don't do this, but is there anything preventing them from?)

Comment: @Pubby: If you compile statically all libraries the compiler would have a chance (I wonder whether it would actually be allowed, and more so, whether compiler writers would even care to byte off a few bits there). If you compile to libraries, the compiler must keep the vptr in case that there is a derived type in a different translation unit... I would really not expect this to be optimized at all

Comment: @Pubby: After a quick think about it, the answer is that it would be insane to try and perform that optimization. The size of the type is used by the compiler whenever an instance of the type is created, or a member of that type is defined in a different class. If the compiler were to remove the vptr, it would have to walk over all uses of the type and fix them to match the new size. For the case of members of different types, that would in turn mean revisiting all uses of those types..., and all that assuming that the program does not have any side effect that depends on those sizes.

Comment: "_Make it virtual. The overhead_" which overhead are you talking about?

Comment: @curiosguy No compiler that I know of (not counting use of `final`), as said in previous comments. The overhead of `virtual` calls and vtable pointer. I assumed the reason OP didn't want to use virtual was because of the slight performance hit.

Answer (score -1):

If you can't modify the code of the base class at all, you can add a function to the derived class like Destroy(). Kind of annoying but we do it all the time if you think of Win32 objects like Brush.

Comment: It would be nice to know why someone down voted this. Did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: I didn't downvote this answer but I do admit to not understanding how it helps. Perhaps you could expand on it? If the function is in the derived class then it implies you have to have a pointer to the derived class to use it anyway, but in this case a straight `delete` is safe too.

Comment: I guess the downvoter's point is that having to cast to the derived class and then explicitly call a Destroy method is just as bad as having to cast to the derived class and calling its destructor. You don't gain anything with that approach.

Comment: Ok, it looks like I misunderstood what to OP was asking.